# Fill arrays applying a function to a given starting value?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a function to fill arrays applying a function to a given starting value?

```
$now  = date('Y');
$down = 5;

// 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008
$years = array_fill_func();
```

Comment: No, but you can implement one easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
$years = range(date('Y'), date('Y') - 4, -1);
```

Comment: That's very good. I found that last parameter is not needed: `$years  = range($t = date('Y'), $t - $down)` is the correct too!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using numbers you can do something like this:

```
$now  = date('Y');
$down = 5;
$years = range($now, $now-$down);
```

Comment: Yes, just numbers for now, but just for curiosity i'm looking also for generic objects.

Comment: @Gremo: [`range`](http://php.net/range) only works on values that can be added/subtracted (ints and strings (characters)).

Comment: @Gremo: in that case you could combine range + array_map

Comment: @zerkms interesting... some hints on how?

Comment: @Gremo: with range you generate the array of expected size and after that you apply your callback function with array_map

Comment: $yearsArray = array_map(function($value) { return 'Year_'.$value; } ,range(2015,2011)); with PHP >= 5.3.0 just to demonstrate applying an alpha prefix